# highcharts legend items align to the left when width is set

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have a highchart with a legend. 
I made the legend have a fixed width of 380px, and I would like to have the legend items always aligned to the right inside this legend box. They align to the left by default instead.

Those are the properties of the legend:

```
... legend: {
        align: 'right', //this align the legend box , not the items
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        borderWidth: 1,
        width: 380,
        floating: true,
        x: -35,
        symbolRadius: 0,
        symbolWidth: 10,
        symbolHeight: 10,
        enabled: true,
        itemStyle: { //I even tried this but with no lick
            textAlign: 'right',
        }
    }, ...
```

And this the legend box is how it looks like:

[image]

I would like those 2 items to be on the right of the box.

Here is a jsfiddle of the graph not doing what I want:

http://jsfiddle.net/MaurizioPiccini/d746v/9/

**What  I have tried:**

1- Putting this in my CSS only changes the alignment of the text inside the item, but it does not align the items to the right of the box.

```
.highcharts-legend-item span {
     text-align:right!important;
}
```

2- adding this as a property on the legend align the legend box , not the items

```
 align: 'right',
```

3- adding this as a property on the legend just does not work either:

```
itemStyle: { //I even tried this but with no lick
    textAlign: 'right',
}
```

Comment: According to the docs, that looks like you have it right. Do you have an example we can see this happening on? (or a ZIP file, with your current text files in)

Comment: @AndrewNewby I added a jsfiddle

Comment: having a look, I think the problem is that the `align` option is actually to do with the floating of the div itself (not the contents in it). For example, using **center** would center the div into the middle of the page. I had a quick play, but can't seem to find the right class to align it centered.

Comment: @AndrewNewby sure but that is written in the original question, beside the align property. ;)

Comment: oh yeah :) I'll try and have another look later, if time permits. Otherwise - maybe someone else has some ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it's not supported. However, you can try to achieve that by manually translating legend group to the right side. You will need to update that position on each chart resize, or whenever legend is redrawn.

Here is sample for it: http://jsfiddle.net/d746v/10/

```
                this.legend.allItems[0].legendGroup.attr({ // 0 - first series, 1 - second series etc.
                    translateX: 320
                });
```

So for each item you will need to calculate proper position.

Answer (score 0):

You could try: `text-align: right;` instead of "align"; 
Or you could try to specify the element in CSS further like:

```
div .example p {

}
```

I hope this solves your problem. Good luck!

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

Comment: No. I actually even tried to set the textAlign property on the itemstyle but it did not work

Comment: Is there perhaps another element that has an "!important" tag behind <br />the align property? "!important" overrules every other rule.

Comment: I tried also '.highcharts-legend-item span {   text-align:right!important; }' in my css. but it changes only the text inside the item, and not the item itself.

Comment: Hmm I see you tried textAlign, but the correct code is text-align. But it could be that it would only move the text again. Is it CSS2/3? Or did I get the tags wrong?

Comment: textAling is the javascirpt version of text-align

Comment: Hmmm I'm used to CSS. When I would set up the legend you have there I would have a background and border set on the <DIV> element (perhaps with a class) and specify the CSS rule further by selecting the <P> and <img> elements inside the div. I don't know how this works inside Javascript. Goodluck!